# How to download Paypal rest api SDK jar

Tags: api, rest, paypal, jar, sdk

I need to integrate my app with Payapl rest API. we are not using maven. so i need to download paypal rest api sdk jar file and put in my lib folder.

Please tell me the link for downloading Paypal rest api SDK jar ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The Git hub location is: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK

If you need the jar, you can go to the Maven repository at: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paypal.sdk/rest-api-sdk
and click the appropriate version you need. After you click the appropriate version, under "files", click "jar" to get the jar. If you also want all the files like the source, javadoc, or pom, click the "view all" link.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I winded up going on github and downloading the sdk project and compiling it into a jar. It's got some dependencies too that need to be included. Wish I could upload the jars here because I know it must be alot of people having the same issue. But if you're reading this and you need those jars, shoot me an email at coreykhharden@gmail.com and I'll drop em to you in an email.